# Mongoose find all documents which matches every entries of an array of ids

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of MongoDB Ids like this: 
`networks = ["5e1cfabb61e9314617fe2db5", "5e1cfbbbe519704860d9a720", "5e1cfbdd4ab5514888b4c6eb"]`

I need to push in a new array all documents (the full object) from my database that matches every entry of networks array.

So I want a new like, lets say peopleNetworks to be like this:

```
`peopleNetworks = [
  {
    "_id": "5e1cfabb61e9314617fe2db5",
    "name": "Facebook",
    "createdAt": "2020-01-13T23:18:19.593Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T23:18:19.593Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e1cfbbbe519704860d9a720",
    "name": "Instagram",
    "createdAt": "2020-01-13T23:22:35.057Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-01-13T23:22:35.057Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e1cfbdd4ab5514888b4c6eb",
    "name": "Vero",
    "createdAt": "2020-01-13T23:23:09.501Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-01-14T00:00:05.458Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]`
```

I tried to filter my collection using the networks array like this:

```
`const peopleNetworks = [];
 const storedNetworks = await Network.find();
 storedNetworks.filter(network => { networks.forEach(id => 
  {
   if (id === network._id) peopleNetworks.push(network);
  })
 );`
```

But it doesn't work.

I think the proper way to do this is by chaining the filter after .find() but I messed up when I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator. Something like

```
await Network.find({ _id: { $in: networks } });
```

This should return you the desired documents and you don't have to fetch all and then filter

Answer (score 0):

You can use $in operator of mongodb with find

```
const storedNetworks = await Network.find({"_id":{"$in":networks}});
```